# Ubuntu disk checking stuck at 33%

Tags: 20.04, virtualbox, squashfs

I used Oracle VirtualBox to install Ubuntu 20.04.1, and it is stuck at 33% when checking disks (it says "Checking ./pool/restricted/l/l Checking ./casper/filesystem.squashfs". Ctrl+C doesn't abort it. Is there any way to either skip this or make it work?

Comment: I keep turning it off and trying again, and it keeps stopping, but at random percentages, the biggest being 77%.